# Button no longer working in game window, but works fine in .exe build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

So last night my game was working just fine.  I log on today and I change an (unrelated) sprite and now for some reason the button won't be clicked in the game window during play mode.  It does however work perfectly on an .exe build.

It's just the button that both players hit to say that they are ready to play the game.

Here are the relevant pieces of code pertaining to this button.  The code that makes the button the code the button calls, etc.
https://gist.github.com/robofriven/ce26f24204dc0149c793

Sorry if this has already been asked, I do a lot of searching before asking questions and thus haven't had to ask anything yet, but this one has me stumped and I can't find anything similar anywhere.  Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "answer your question" part at the bottom and was just trying to keep it caught up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently it has to do with the screen resolution not set to free aspect and that tweaking how the buttons respond to mouse clicks.  It's kind of a phantom mouse thing where the mouse is not really pointing where it thinks it's pointing.